# После компилирования кода на pascal и открытия программы, она вылетает

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Компилирую код на pascal. Открываю exe. Ввожу значения, нажимаю enter и программу выкидывает, помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно!!!

```
var
  a, b, c: integer;

begin
  write('write a,b: ');
  readln(a, b);
  while b <> 0 do
  begin
    c := a mod b;
    a := b;
    b := c;
  end;
  writeln('The NOD is ', a);
end.
```

Программа pascalABC

Comment: "программу выкидывает" - ??

Comment: да, выкидывает, даже ошибки не выдает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `readln;` перед `end.`
Возможно дело в том, что консоль закрывается сразу после срабатывания программы и вы не успеваете увидеть результат. `readln;` позволит остановить консоль до следующей нажатой клавиши.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Разобрался